# mysql not releasing pool connection after query

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript, npm, es6-promise

Using the `mysql` nodeJS module, I created a small database typescript file to help me handle the pools and queries.

First function is `connect` which returns a promise

```
static connect(): Promise<any> {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  fs.readFile('includes/config.txt', (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log('seems like config.txt file is corrupted, ignore message if connection established');
    } else {
      data = data.toString().split('\n');
      host = data[0].substr(3);
      user = data[1].substr(5);
      password = data[2].substr(5);
      pool = mysql.createPool({
        host: host,
        user: user,
        password: password,
        database: DB_NAME,
        connectionLimit: 10
      });
      pool.on('release', (connection) => {
        console.log('releasing your connection now');
      });
      pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
        if (err) { reject(err); }
        resolve(connection);
      });
    }
  });
});};
```

and then I have another function `spQuery' that helps me query, then release the connection once query is complete

```
static spQuery(command: string, data, req?): Promise<any> {
data.push(JSON.stringify(adata));
command = command.slice(0, command.lastIndexOf('?') + 1) + ', ?)';
console.log('Command: ' + command);
console.log('Values: ' + data);
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  this.connect().then(conn => {
    sqlConn = conn;
    sqlConn.query(command, data, (err, results) => {
      if(err){
        reject(err);
      } else{
        results = results[0];
        resolve(results)
      }
    });
  }).catch(err => {
    return reject(err);
  }).then( () => {
    sqlConn.release();
  });
});}
```

Now what I'm thinking might be wrong is inside the `spQuery` function, I think i might be releasing the sqlConnection before the `sqlConn.query(...)` is done executing, becuase the `sqlConn.release();` is inside the `.then()` of the first `connect` function... however if I move the `sqlConn.release();` into inside the callback of `sqlConn.query` I get an error saying

> Error: Connection already released